# How does Stack Overflow determine for how long to keep a question in the main page?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, homepage

I am guessing this has to do with the amount of views, answers, upvotes and time it was posted but is there a place where I can get a more detailed explanation of this?

Also I have seen questions asked several months ago re-appear because they have many views/upvotes.

Comment: AFAIK, it's up there for as long as it doesn't get bumped off by more recent active questions and isn't negatively downvoted for some amount of time. (there's others such as delting, migration, etc.)  A post is "active" when an answer is submitted, an edit was made or other action that usually has a revision.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jeff explained this in detail on [the Stack Exchange blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/):

> Here’s how it works. Starting with a list of the last 3,000 active
> questions:
>
> - drop questions containing any of your ignored tags
> - drop closed questions if you lack the reputation required to vote for reopening
> - drop questions scoring -4 or lower
>
> Next, apply the following score formula to the remaining questions:
>
> - **your [interesting tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/expressing-your-tag-preferences/):** +1,500 per interesting tag, up to +2,000 total
> - **your top 40 scoring tags:** maximum of +1,000 per tag (scaled), up to +2,000 total
> - **question score:** +200 × score, up to +1,000 total
> - **total answer score:** -200 × score, up to -1,000 total
> - **number of answers:** -200 × answers, up to -1,000 total
> - **number of views:** -15 × views, up to -1,000 total
> - **question last activity date:** -1 × (seconds / 15)
>
> Count it all up and take the top 90 by score.
>
> We also mix in a few random questions from the last 3,000 — 10% (9)
> for logged in users and 20% (18) for anonymous users. We’re like DJs
> trying to spin a mix of songs — some you might know by heart and love,
> others you might not have chosen for yourself, but could possibly like
> if you gave them a fair listen.

On Metas, the threshold to drop questions (the 3rd bullet) [is -8 or lower](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62729/meta-sites-front-pages-should-not-hide-questions-with-very-low-scores/62769#62769).

Comment: Wow, how fast does that computation run? It seems really intensive.