# Why do downvotes detract reputation from poster on meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, meta

I read somewhere that downvotes on meta simply means that someone doesn't agree with you. But on Stack Overflow, downvotes typically mean the question is low quality or off topic. I completely understand why downvotes detract reputation from the poster (whose post is being downvoted) on Stack Overflow, but I don't understand it here.

I understand that all voting is subjective, but I feel that on meta, voting is purposefully subjective - Hence the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag.

Could somebody explain the philosophy behind detracting reputation from users whose meta posts are downvoted?

Comment: No, voting can still be very much based on the quality of the post on Meta. Users are molly-coddling each other when they only believe it's based on disagreement

Comment: You will primarily see such voting when you propose something radical like a feature-request. Aside from that, the quality of the answer is taken into consideration, and isn't strictly opinion based.

Comment: @random Okay, I see some of that. But what about a discussion or proposal for a feature - that you just don't agree with. By downvoting that post, you are costing the poster reputation, even though it may have been a well written post

Comment: It may have been a well formed post, but votes can also exercise their votes as they wish. Say, if they don't think the discussion needs to happen yet again. Or if they think not enough research was done. Or if it's coming from a false premise. Or if it's any manner of reason that makes them click down. Which may or may not include disagreeing, but is certainly not the only factor

Comment: @random I see your point. I guess this comes back to leaving a comment when you downvote.

Comment: @random Also, please note that the duplicate you chose was talking about the voter losing reputation. I am talking about the poster losing reputation.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133787/voting-meta-vs-other-sites http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/the-meaning-of-down-votes-in-meta-vs-stackoverflow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying