# Question not appearing on Stack Overflow home page

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, homepage

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130168/c-source-file-inclusion-in-objective-c) question on Stack Overflow with [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) tags, but the question is not appearing on the front page. I tried to edit it so that it could get bumped but to vain. Can anyone tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: I can see this question at #5 in [C++ Newest questions list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?sort=newest&pageSize=30). In which page you are looking?

Comment: Yes. But, it's not on the default page: stackoverflow.com ; where most people look.

Comment: I see it as #4 on the front page.

Comment: Why did you delete it?? You got a valid answer and even upvote. Anyway, the homepage default display show random questions based on a [complicated formula](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106981/152859)

Answer (score 2):

The homepage (https://stackoverflow.com/) shows interesting questions by default. There are another tabs in the homepage like [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured), [hot](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot), [week](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week), and [month](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month). Which show questions as per their descriptions. The problem is you believe that most people look at homepage which is not correct. Most people look at tagged page with their interesting tags. E.g. I look at [tagged page with SQL tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql). So it will show me questions tagged with [sql](/questions/tagged/sql). Most people see either [newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++?sort=newest&pageSize=30) or [active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++?sort=active&pageSize=30) tab where your question appears right now. So you don't need to worry about it.