# Return the - 1 reputation hit for downvoting a question

Tags: feature-request, reputation, questions, voting, down-votes

Now that we've raised the reward for asking a good question, why don't we revert the other change to question votes and deduct 1 reputation from someone downvoting a question? I think this would help solve a common issue where questions are downvoted into oblivion because it costs the downvoter nothing.

Comment: With the change to upvotes on questions (without a similar change to downvotes), question downvotes are now comparably weaker than they were in the past. On top of that, you're asking to lessen the amount of downvotes by dissuading lower rep users? Can you elaborate on why a question being downvoted is something you want to prevent?

Comment: We don't need less downvotes, we need more.

Comment: @sco Because it is often done excessively and sometimes in a knee jerk reaction. This way it would be done carefully.

Comment: What happens if someone ends up with negative reputation as a result?

Comment: @Rebecca They would stop being able to downvote before that. If you mean when rep is recalculated, it could just be set to 1.

Comment: The claims of 'knee-jerk' reactions, and the like, are often made, usually without any evidence of any such problem. What we really need is many more effective curators and to somehow dissuade the bad, biased ones, e.g. those who have issued 6 times more upvotes than downvotes.

Comment: No no no, please no! The votes are already heavily skewed towards upvoting; if this were implemented, in an environment where rating things low is perceived as a personal insult, no one would downvote anymore, legitimate reason or not.

Answer (score 6):

> I think this would help solve a common issue where questions are downvoted into oblivion because it costs the downvoter nothing.

This may or may not be a good idea, but from the proposal, it's not possible to say.

#### The aim...

...is to avoid questions being downvoted into oblivion.

1. *Is this even a problem?*  Outside of Meta.SE, my experience is that the heavily downvoted posts are wildly off-topic, inappropriate, spam, or poorly written.  The "problem" is already alleviated when [questions with sufficiently negative scores are hidden from the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106979/how-does-stack-overflow-determine-for-how-long-to-keep-a-question-in-the-main-pa).
2. *If it were a problem, would this even fix the problem?*  There's no evidence given for its efficacy.
3. *Would introduce other problems?*

   1. Question downvotes are used for [automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba), so discouraging downvoting questions would interfere with this process.  Likewise for [question bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).
   2. Already-made downvotes were cast with the knowledge of how reputation is affected.  Maybe the users would have voted differently had they known.

      Some users use downvotes as a kind of "garbage identification", and they tend to go underappreciated.  This would be a bit of a slap in the face.
   3. Until a user [reaches a certain reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down), they cannot downvote.  If the change is made retrospectively, there will be some downvotes that violate this rule.
4. *Is this the best way to solve this problem?*  Off the top of my head, there are other plausible solutions:

   1. Ask users not to downvote questions into oblivion, e.g. use a prompt.
   2. Add a hard-cap to negative scores.
   3. Give +1 rep for upvoting.
5. *Does it suit every site?*  The voting cultures on different sites are wildly different.

#### The evidence...

...is "I think".  This proposal requires substantially more investigation.

Comment: Re: Giving +1 rep for to the voter for (indiscriminate) upvoting, this could be the end of civilization as we know it

Comment: Alright, I have to admit, that's a bad idea.  (: