# Setting a benchmark on negative marking on question/answer for auto delete

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, voting, down-votes

Just a thought: Shouldn't there be a way, if a benchmark is been set for `vote-down` and on basis of that, the particular post should be hidden/deleted/disappear from the list and looks clean with no unhelpful content into it?

I know there is an auto close feature which gets tagged if votes goes below 5.

Usually when we see particular post having ***negative***/***vote-down*** more than 3-4 times then we don't pay much attention to that particular post itself. Hence what if we can remove that post from that particular chain so there is no unnecessary junk laying over.

For example:

If there is a particular question / answer has been marked ***negative***/***vote-down***  ***(x) number of times*** then it will be moved out permanently. I do understand there is a high complexity involved into since there are different scenarios involved into it.

#### Scenario - 1

If there is an answer and have high number of vote-downs/negative marking then that particular answer can be removed easily. However, what if, that answer contains comments into it? What will happen to the comments which are posted on that particular answer?

#### Scenario - 2

In this case, if the main parent question has been marked negative multiple times, then what will happen to all the answers which has been posted? If this question has been marked negative so many times then is it necessary for that particular question to remain in the system when it doesn't offer any help/use for other users?

Comment: *I know there is auto close feature* ... I was unaware of that.

Comment: You know the [roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)?

Comment: Your question seems to contain lots of misconceptions. I think you should look at the help-centre. E.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers or https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might not be aware, but something like this is already in place:

- Negatively scoring questions (-4 or lower) are already [hidden from the homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106981/295232).

  - If you wait long enough, they will be deleted by [an automated process](/help/roomba).
- Negatively scoring answers (-3 or lower) are grayed out

  - Those answers are also more likely to be flagged as Very Low Quality and eventually deleted via the review queues.
  - Sometimes, a negatively scoring answer is helping to indicate what people with the same problem as the question author should *not* try.

Comment: probably worth also mentioning that original design of triage review ([currently abandoned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374881/839601)) supposed to hide troublesome questions from most if not all views