# Why are "Last seen", "xxx profile views", "Member for", and "Visited xxx days, xxx consecutive" information now missing from the Profile page?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

Today I noticed that the following information is missing from the Profile page:

- Last seen
- xxx profile views

The following are visible only for my own profile, but not for others:

- Member for xx year, xx month
- Visited xxx days, xxx consecutive

Example: [new version](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4767/oded?tab=profile), [old version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHSVw.png).

What is the reason for the removal?

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing Thanks.  Strangely [that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive) is not in the [main page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Anonymous it's not strange - take a look at the score of the question - it is far under -8 (? not sure how accurate the info is, though, if anyone knows of a more recent question than [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106979/786798), please share)

Comment: I think the limit is -10 (vote total?). That question (currently at -106/+18 (-88)) ought to be ***featured***; otherwise it is effectively deleted. Currently, only *"[Join me in Welcoming Valued Associates: #945 - Slate - and #948 - Vanny](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367910)"*) is featured. Or someone could ***sacrifice*** at least 50 reputation points to get it some attention (by a bounty). At least it was not done ***on a Friday*** (though for many it effectively was).

Comment: [Spectric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14251221/) have created an awesome [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/9074/) that get those data from Stack Exchange API.

Comment: reason for the removal: because they can, and don't care. Simple as that.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q your wish is my command - started a bounty on it