# Are there changes in the format of user profiles?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

Until a few days ago, I could click on the name of a user and see for how long they've been a user and when they last used the site. But now it seems this information is not available anymore. Is this temporary? Or was that a requested change?

Comment: Oops, I am really late : ) I had searched for "user profile" but this question strangely didn't come up. Thanks.

Comment: You are excused. It is currently at -106/+18 (-88) and it [is automatically hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368298/why-last-seen-xxx-profile-views-member-for-and-visited-xxx-days-xxx-c#comment1228343_368298).

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you for explaining. I really hope they put this data back. While it may be considered vanity for users themselves, it was of great help for me to assess the experience other users had on certain sites... And the "Last seen" button was truly helpful in particular situations.

Comment: Feel free to post an "answer" if it's not already been said by someone else.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's a really long read, but searching the word "experienced" helped. The issue has been mentioned.

Comment: The highest upvoted answer? I was thinking if the stats were useful for other things. For example, seeing why someone didn't post a reply to a comment or a request for clarification, knowing how long the OP has been offline/away helps everyone to be more patient/tolerant. And with new users seeing that they've posted a Q and have not returned since means I don't waste my time commenting.