# Why is the question with the newest bounty, with score < -100, not in the bountied tab?

Tags: support, bounties, bountied-tab

I know [Don't close questions where the user has requested that it not be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed) has **A LOT** of downvotes, but it is a bountied question and it deserves its time in the limelight (aka the [bountied tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured)).

- [Discussion in the Tavern about this](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/797592#797592)
- [Possible answer, but needs more references](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62729/meta-sites-front-pages-should-not-hide-questions-with-very-low-scores/62769#62769)

Comment: @jonsca lol I am not sure where you are looking.

Comment: @jonsca Apparently there are two featured lists.  It doesn't appear on one of them: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116150/why-are-there-two-featured-lists

Comment: @jonsca I added the link I am talking about.

Comment: @AdamDavis I see what you mean now.  I just read your newest meta question.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Yes, apologies, I just followed Adam's link to see the "Bizarro" Featured page.  This is very strange.

Comment: @Chris that is already linked in the OP :-P

Comment: I think the "possible answer" is right; I expanded on that thought a bit [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116154/131713).

Comment: Odd, [it *does* show](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116212/these-numbers-are-too-crowded-can-we-give-them-some-breathing-room) on the active tab of Top Questions. So the rules for the downvotes seem not very consistent.

Comment: @Arjan hmmmm yea, that is odd..