# Why are there two featured lists?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bountied-tab

There are two featured lists with the same URL, but different results:

1. Go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com
2. Click on "Questions"
3. Click on "featured"

You'll see one list with the URL https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured

1. Go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com
2. Click on "featured"

This list is subtly different - in this case it's missing a certain 500 point bounty - and perhaps others.  It has the URL https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured

Caching issue, or gnomes?

Comment: Related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116148/155556

Comment: Note that 1st list (the tab in All Questions) is also the link one sees in "Browse the complete list" on the 2nd list (the tab in Top Questions).

Answer (score 10):

I think that, with method two, you're still technically "on the front page" — just seeing a restricted view of it — where the [no questions with score of -8 or lower rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62729/meta-sites-front-pages-should-not-hide-questions-with-very-low-scores/62769#62769) applies.

With the first method, you're inside `/questions`, so you see everything.

Comment: That seems the most likely explanation. Still not convinced that the two distinct paths are warranted, though.

Comment: Agreed. What's better than winning a 500-point bounty? Winning a 500-point bounty _and_ the Reversal badge!

Comment: Also note the different naming: Top Questions versus All Questions. And when there were 15 open bounties the list on Top Questions was 14 long, while some time when another bounty was opened, it grew to be 15 long. In both lists, the downvoted one was not to be seen. It indeed seems to be explicitly hidden from Top Questions.