# Problem in number of featured questions...?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, featured-tag

[image: featured questions]

I see 313 featured questions but this is 314 in side bar...is there any problem with me or my account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seriously doubt it is a problem with your account. It's probably just a caching inconsistency... it should correct itself soon enough.

You could always logout, clear your cache, and refresh to confirm that it isn't a problem with your account. (Or just open up an incognito window or something).

Answer (score 3):

In this case it's probably just caching, so: refresh.

However, from another answer I once wrote in [Sorting order of featured questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91034/sorting-order-of-featured-questions/113014#113014):

> There are actually [two featured lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116150/why-are-there-two-featured-lists): one when viewing [Top Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured), and another when viewing [All Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured). Bounties with a (very?) negative vote count, [are not shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116148/why-is-the-question-with-the-newest-bounty-with-score-100-not-in-the-featur) on the first (the list will even shrink if there are few other active bounties), but will still show on the latter.

Comment: thanks for your good reply but i can't mark all as correct answer.